# Istio canary updates using yaml files

Tags: kubernetes, istio, argocd, gitops

Reading Istio documentation about who to perform [canary upgrades][1] for Istio itself is confusing. I don't understand how the procedure should go and what to expect in every step of it, further more, it does not cover an upgrade by means of yaml files when also using an operator.

What would a high level summary of the steps for updating IsitioOperator CR in a Kubernetes cluster using only yamls. Considering for example Kubernetes 1.18 and Istio 1.7.x to 1.9.x update. yamls could be generated by means of "helm" or "istioctl" but at the end of the day, the update should be performed by "kubectl apply" commands (since ArgoCD is in place for applying GitOps way of deployment).

Error example to answer one of the questions in comments:

```
2021-04-29T08:19:27.727502Z     info    klog    attempting to acquire leader lease  istio-operator/istio-operator-lock-1-8-5...[]
2021-04-29T08:19:27.740752Z     info    klog    successfully acquired lease istio-operator/istio-operator-lock-1-8-5[]
2021-04-29T08:19:32.349465Z     info    installer       Reconciling IstioOperator
2021-04-29T08:19:32.349837Z     info    installer       Ignoring IstioOperator CR example-istiocontrolplane with revision , since operator revision is 1-8-5.
2021-04-29T08:31:41.222974Z     info    installer       Reconciling IstioOperator
2021-04-29T08:31:41.223180Z     info    Adding finalizer istio-finalizer.install.istio.io to istio-system/example-istiocontrolplane-1-8-5
2021-04-29T08:31:41.250667Z     info    installer       Could not add finalizer to example-istiocontrolplane-1-8-5 due to conflict. Operation will be retried in next reconcile attempt.
```

Comment: Have you checked the istio operator canary upgrade [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator/#canary-upgrade)? At least for me it's clear on how to proceed with that. Note if you're planning to upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9 you would have to upgrade from 1.7 to 1.8 first. Let me know if you have any more questions regarding this topic.

Comment: I followed those guides and more particularly, [this one](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator/#canary-upgrade) but nothing. Also trying 1.7.3 to 1.8.5 it fails. In istio-operator-1-8-5-xxxx logs I can see the error I'll add in the description now. I tried updating via manifests, istioctl but nothing, always unexpected behaviours.